# Найти среднее арифметическое всех элементов массива, которые ∈(x, y] (x, y вводить с клавиатуры)

Tags: c, олимпиада

Найти среднее арифметическое всех элементов массива, которые ∈(x, y] (x, y вводить с клавиатуры).

```
int massiv[7];
printf(" \n", i);
for (i=1; i<=7; i++)
scanf("%d", &massiv[i]);
printf("x y");
scanf("%d", &x, &y);
int avg,x,y;
x=0;
y=0;
avg = 0;
for (i=1; i<=7; i++)
{
avg += massiv[i];
}
avg = avg / 7;
printf("avg=%d\n", avg);
}
все что смог сделать
```

Comment: что такое A, где заполнение massiv?

Comment: Исправил @Elena_Gnil ….

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не реализовали проверку на вхождение в диапазон `(x, y)`. Сделать это можно с помощью простого условия:

```cpp
massiv[i] > x && massiv[i] < y
```

Но так как не все числа могут входить в диапазон, дополнительно вы должны подсчитывать количество нужных чисел:

```cpp
int amt = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    if (massiv[i] > x && massiv[i] < y) {
        avg += massiv[i];
        amt++;
    }
}
```

Также нужно учесть, что тип `int` не позволяет хранить дробные числа. А среднее арифметическое часто оказывается дробным числом. Используйте тип `double` для переменной `avg`, чтобы не потерять точность:

```cpp
double avg;
avg = avg / amt;
```

---

В коде ещё много ошибок:

- Не заполняете первый элемент массива и выходите за его границу
- Не указываете строку формата для инициализации `y`
- Обнуляете ввод пользователя
- При выводе `avg` указываете, что это целое число